# Регулярные выражения для строки координат

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Составить регулярное выражение для поиска одинарных кавычек после двух цифр в строке координат
44°58'49.9"N 34°06'00.5"E

пока написал только [^\d+\w\s.\°], это хорошо работает когда в строке только координаты, если имеется еще текст то соответственно не работает

Comment: `[^\d+\w\s.\°]` никак не может работать хорошо. Какой метод используете, на каком языке пишете код? Если у вас текст `44°58'49.9"N 34°06'00.5"E`, какой должен быть результат?

Comment: python re

заменить одинарные кавычки на m

Comment: `re.sub(r"(?<=\d)'(?=\d)", "m", text)`?

Comment: Ну, как, помогло моё решение?